# Store data in MKAnnotation?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, mkmapview, mkannotation

So I'm pretty new to Xcode and Objective-C. I have several ArtPiece objects with various attributes stored in an array. I then add them as MKAnnotations to the mapview. What I need to be able to do is send a reference to the array position they came from on click. I believe MKAnnotations only have the data members title, image, and location, so when I make an MKAnnotation from the objects, the annotation does not keep any of the other attributes. So, my question is, how can I manage to keep a reference to the array position of the object the annotation was created from so that I can send it to other methods so they can retrieve the additional information about the object from the array for detail views etc.  Is there any way to store a single int value in an annotation? I don't think there is so any other ideas?

Here is my ArtPiece.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface ArtPiece : NSObject <MKAnnotation>{

    NSString *title;
    NSString *artist;
    NSString *series;
    NSString *description;
    NSString *location;
    NSString *area;
    NSNumber *latitude;
    NSNumber *longitude;
    UIImage *image;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *artist;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *series;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *location;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *area;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;


@end
```

and here is the .m:

```
#import "ArtPiece.h"
#import "FindArtController.h"
#import "ArtPiece.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@implementation ArtPiece

- (NSString *)description{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"title: %@",title];
}

@synthesize title, artist, series, description, latitude, longitude, location, area, image;

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    theCoordinate.latitude = [self.latitude doubleValue];
    theCoordinate.longitude = [self.longitude doubleValue];
    return theCoordinate;
}




@end
```

I then go on to make objects of that class, set their values, and add them to an array in the AppDelegate. Then, in another class, I use:

```
[self.mapView addAnnotations:mainDelegate.mapAnnotations];
```

to add the annotations to the map. However, when I try to set the "artist" attribute in the viewforannotation method, I get "request for member artist in something not a structure or union."

Obviously, I must be doing this subclassing thing wrong, but what do I change?

Here is the viewforannotation method I have now. The test.artist... line is not working.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    MKAnnotationView *test=[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"reuse"];
    test.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pao_pin.png"];
    [test setCanShowCallout:YES];
    [test setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    test.rightCalloutAccessoryView =
    [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    test.artist = annotation.artist;
    return test;    
}
```

So, should I: `annotation = (ArtPiece *)annotation`
In short, my goal is to be able to store a reference to the array position of the object in this annotation was made from so that I can send that to other methods who can access that object for detail views etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the `viewForAnnotation` method, you can access your `ArtPiece` properties but to avoid compiler errors and warnings, you'll need to first cast the `annotation` parameter to your custom class.  The `annotation` parameter in that method is just defined as a `id<MKAnnotation>` so the compiler won't know about the ArtPiece-specific properties (until you tell it that is an instance of `ArtPiece`).

You'll need something like this:

```
ArtPiece *artPiece = (ArtPiece *)annotation;
NSString *artist = artPiece.artist;
```

**Edit:**
When an annotation view's callout button is pressed, the map view calls the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method.  This method gets passed the `MKAnnotationView` in the `view` parameter.  The annotation object itself is in the `annotation` property of the `view` parameter.  You can cast that object to your custom class to access your `ArtPiece` properties:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    ArtPiece *artPiece = (ArtPiece *)view.annotation;
    NSString *artist = artPiece.artist;
}
```

In other words, the callout button handler doesn't need to access the original array.  It gets a reference to the actual `ArtPiece` object itself.

Comment: That is what i was going to say, MKAnnotations can literally be any object that meets the minimum requirements.

Comment: I added my viewforannotation method and a brief explanation. Is there a simple fix in there or do I need to make some bigger changes enable my annotation to keep an "artist" or eventually "arrayposition" data member.

Comment: So if the user taps the annotation's disclosure button, you want to know which ArtPiece it is.  Is that correct?

Comment: That's exactly right. I've been able to do this in a tableview just by using the row number, but doing this with annotations has given me some trouble.

Comment: Thank you, and if this helps make it any more clear, if my array of artpieces has 10 objects, I need the annotation to be able to send a message with simply an integer 1 through 10 to tell another method which array position the object the said annotation was made from so that the other method can go and access all the attributes of it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of MKAnnotation and you can add whatever additional data members you need.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think that's kind of what I tried to do in my ArtPiece class but I must be doing it wrong. I edited my question to show more code. Any additional help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you want to subclass `MKAnnotationView`, not `NSObject`.

Comment: @Ryan, are you trying to _set_ an artist property on the _view_ instead of _getting_ the property from the annotation?  In that case, Mark is correct that you'd need to subclass MKAnnotationView.  If you explain what you're trying to do in viewForAnnotation more, that will help (and I'll remove my answer).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some confusion here.

`MKAnnotation` is a protocol, not a class, so you don't subclass it, you implement it. Any object can be an `MKAnnotation` as long as it implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol (coordinate, title, subtitle) and that object can have any other property you like if you're creating it. You have done that correctly above.

Oftentimes you will need to cast that `<MKAnnotation>` to your custom class, as Anna Karenina said, to inform the compiler what type of object it is.

`MKAnnotationView` on the other hand is a class (and a subclass of `UIView`), and if you want to create your own you can subclass it. Then when it is created and used by the map it holds a reference to its associated `MKAnnotation`, so in your custom `MKAnnotationView` you can:

```
self.artistLabel.text = [(ArtPiece *)self.annotation artist];
```

Answer (score 1):

Every annotation has unique id. Use `NSMutableDictionary` and use your annotation unique id as key for any objects you want. later you could access when you call this:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
```