# Label keeps displaying last item in plist

Tags: ios, plist, uistoryboardsegue, mkannotationview

I'm building an iPhone app and my label keeps grabbing the last item in my plist. The first portion of the app displays a map with annotations. The annotations -- latitude and longitude along with a title are all being pulled from the same plist as well.

Here is my code:

```
 #import "myMapViewController.h"
    #import "MapViewAnnotation.h"

    @interface myMapViewController ()
    @property NSArray *states;
    //@property NSString *nameString;
    //@property NSString *zipString;
    //@property NSString *subtitleString;
   //@property NSString *zipString;
    @end

    @implementation myMapViewController

    @synthesize mapView;



    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;  //showsUserLocation = YES;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    [self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated: YES];
    [self.mapView addAnnotations:[self createAnnotations]];

    //[self zoomToLocation];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSMutableArray *)createAnnotations
{
    NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"States" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *rootLevel = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    int count = rootLevel.count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){

        NSDictionary *secondLevel = [rootLevel objectAtIndex:i];
        // NSArray *state = [secondLevel valueForKey:@"State"];
        NSArray *stores = [secondLevel valueForKey:@"Stores"];


        for (NSDictionary *row in stores) {
            NSString *latitude = [row objectForKey:@"Latitude"];
            NSString *longitude = [row objectForKey:@"Longitude"];
            NSString *title = [row objectForKey:@"Name"];

            NSString *nameString = [row objectForKey:@"Number"];
            NSString *zipString = [row objectForKey:@"Zip"];
            NSString *subtitle = [row objectForKey:@"Address1"];

            //Create coordinates from the latitude and longitude values
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
            coord.latitude = latitude.doubleValue;
            coord.longitude = longitude.doubleValue;

            MapViewAnnotation *annotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:title AndCoordinate:coord AndZipString:zipString AndNameString:nameString AndSubSubtitle:subtitle];

            [annotations addObject:annotation];

            //set label


        }
    }
    return annotations;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showStoreDetails"])
    {



        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = sender;
        id<MKAnnotation> ann = annotationView.annotation;
       [segue.destinationViewController setNameString:ann.title];
       [segue.destinationViewController setZipString:ann.title];
        NSLog(@"log %@", annotationView.annotation.subtitle);

    }
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)sender viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
{
    static NSString *reuseId = @"StandardPin";

    MKPinAnnotationView *aView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[sender
                                                         dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];

    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation){
        return nil; //default to blue dot
    }

    if (aView == nil)
    {
        aView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
        aView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        aView.canShowCallout = YES;
        //aView.animatesDrop = YES;
    }

    aView.annotation = annotation;
    return aView;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showStoreDetails" sender:view];
    NSLog(@"accessory button tapped for annotation %@", view.annotation.title);

}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
    for(MKAnnotationView *annotationView in views) {
        if(annotationView.annotation == mv.userLocation) {
            MKCoordinateRegion region;
            MKCoordinateSpan span;

            span.latitudeDelta=0.7;
            span.longitudeDelta=0.7;

            CLLocationCoordinate2D location=mv.userLocation.coordinate;

            region.span=span;
            region.center=location;

            [mv setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
            [mv regionThatFits:region];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: you mean it keeps showing only last data/record from the plist?

Comment: Completely off-topic, but do you realize that your METERS_PER_MILE constant is wrong?  It should be 1609.344.

Comment: It's not clear at all what your question and/or problem is.  Since there's no mention of a label in your code, what label is being set to the last value?

Answer (score 1):

When you are iterating through your plist, you need an array to store your `namestring` instead of simple `self.namestring` NSString.

Comment: Still pretty new at this.. sample code to help me out a little?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like at no point are you actually giving the `MapViewAnnotation` object the label for the location.

When you loop through the data from the plist the only thing that is happening to the label is it being set to `self.nameString` which will keep getting overwritten by each iteration of the loop.

Not sure exactly what your code is trying to do but it looks like you aren't doing enough with the `name` value to achieve what you want.

Comment: He sets the title (and then the annotation title) to the same value as nameString, so it looks like he's setting the pin title correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. Your inner loop does the job of assigning text to the label. These two loops goes through all the records and keeps assigning the name to the nameString removing the first recorded label

self.nameString = nameString;

And hence stores the last string only.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Kunal

Comment: So what would you suggest to fix?

Comment: please tell me what exactly you want to achieve then only I can help you out!

Comment: The label on my details page (from the map annotation being pressed) is only displaying the last item in my plist. However all of my annotations and titles are correct.. all from the same plist. Regardless of what annotation is pressed.

Comment: So you want only to display the name of the annotation which is being pressed.. correct?

Comment: yes and eventually other items from the list along with a call and directions button. But kinda stuck on this for now.

Comment: you need to send store object to the screen you are navigating to and you will get a name directly from that object

Comment: I thought I was with    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{


    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showStoreDetails"])
    {

        [segue.destinationViewController setNameString:self.nameString];


    }
}

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that in `prepareForSegue`, you are sending `self.nameString` to the `destinationViewController` but that variable contains only the last item read.

Notice that in `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, you are calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` with the `sender` as `view` (ie. *the view of the annotation selected*) **but in `prepareForSegue`, you are not using `sender`**.

You should use `sender` in `prepareForSegue` instead of `self.nameString`.

See [MKAnnotationView Push to View Controller when DetailDesclosure Button is Clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805954/mkannotationview-push-to-view-controller-when-detaildesclosure-button-is-clicked) for a detailed example.

The updated code in `prepareForSegue` might look like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showStoreDetails"])
    {
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = sender;
        id<MKAnnotation> ann = annotationView.annotation;
        [segue.destinationViewController setNameString:ann.title];
    }
}
```

Comment: This make perfect sense. But I am now having trouble getting more information to the details view. Where and how do I add the other items in my plist to pass to other labels.

Comment: In destinationViewController, instead of a setNameString method/property, you can have a method/property to accept the entire `MapViewAnnotation` object.  Then you can pass it `ann` instead of just `ann.title`.

Comment: Please excuse me as I am learning all of this as I go. But I still can't wrap my head around what I need to do. How do I include all of my strings in the MapViewAnnotation object?

Comment: By "other items in the plist" I assumed you meant other details specific to each annotation.  In the MapViewAnnotation class, you currently maybe have only the title and coordinate properties.  You can add the additional info you want to keep with each annotation (address, phone#, hours, etc) and set this info when you create each  annotation.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939223/store-data-in-mkannotation for an example of this.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem might be from the words "still nothing".  Can you please give more details like what NSLogs you see, what steps you do and what happens or what you see, etc?  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger and checked whether each method is called properly, etc?  Also please note you are passing ann.title when calling setZipString.  With SO questions, it's better if you focus on one small problem at a time, close it if that problem is solved and ask another question for the next problem.

Comment: Anna. Thanks for being so patient with me. I have tried adding those methods propertied to the MapViewAnnotation like you mentioned and thought i could get those items to the destinationViewController. I know ann.title always passed the title property from the MapViewAnnotation. But it doesnt recognize anything else but ann.title.. ie: ann.zipString..doesnt work. nothing shows up in the label.

Comment: In prepareForSegue, when calling setZipString, the code is passing ann.title.  Instead, it should pass ann.zip (assuming you created a zip property in MapViewAnnotation).  You need to do some debugging which means confirming each part of the code actually does what you think it should do.  As is, there are too many possibilities of things that could go wrong.