# Sending 'MKPointAnnotation *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<NSCoping>'

Tags: objective-c, mkannotation, mkpointannotation

I have a MKMapView. In this view I create some annotations. When the user clicks on the annotation disclosure button, I want to push to the detail view.

When I create the annotation, I also fill a NSMutableDictionary to be able to grab the store object afterwards with the point as key.

```
MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;
annotationCoord.latitude = [[store storeLatitude] floatValue];
annotationCoord.longitude = [[store storeLongitude] floatValue];

point.coordinate = annotationCoord;

NSString *title = [store storeName];
point.title = title;
point.subtitle = location;

// keep reference to store object with the annotation point as key
[annotationStoreDictionary setObject:store forKey:point];
```

When the user selects the annotation, I want to call the DetailViewController and pass the object:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    DetailViewController *con = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
    Store *store = [annotationStoreDictionary objectForKey:view.annotation];
    con.store = store;

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:con animated:YES];
}
```

The problem is that MKPointAnnotation is not compliant with the NSCoping protocol. It says:

```
Sending 'MKPointAnnotation *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<NSCoping>'
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: As @Jesper suggests, subclass MKPointAnnotation and add custom properties to keep a reference to each annotation's Store in the annotation object itself.  The separate dictionary is not necessary.  Another approach is this: Since you already have a `Store` class, simply make it implement the `MKAnnotation` protocol and add the Store objects themselves to the map.  This way, the annotations _are_ the Stores.  To create a class that implements MKAnnotation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939223/store-data-in-mkannotation for one example.

Comment: +1, @Anna . Implementing `MKAnnotation` is a great alternative.

Comment: @Anna, if you provide this as an answer, I will accept it! Thanks for the input, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use something that doesn't conform to the `NSCopying` protocol as a key in a dictionary. You'll have to use something else that does.

One way of getting around this would be to make a subclass of `MKPointAnnotation` with extra properties for correlation - and in that case, you may as well also just use the extra property or properties on that object and not go through the dictionary in the first place.